# Why my result multithread double and not sequential?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem for my coding "threading"

Here's my coding:

```py
def read_email_from_gmail():
    data = ["one","two","three",'four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']
    for x in data:
        print(f'{x} \n')

threads = input("\n Amount of Thread ?: ")
for i in range(int(threads)):
    threading.Thread(target=read_email_from_gmail).start()
```

I want the result to be sequential when using multithreading, but I get result like this.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTqq9.png)

My expected result is

```
one
two
... until
nine
ten
```

is something wrong with my coding?

**my original coding**

```py
def read_email_from_gmail():
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
        mail.login(ORG_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
        mail.select('inbox')
    
        data = mail.search(None, '(Subject "verify email")' )
        mail_ids = data[1]
        id_list = mail_ids[0].split()
        if not id_list:
            print("No Email Found")
        else: 
            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}----------------------------------------{Fore.RESET}")
            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX}            Found {len(id_list)} Email{Fore.RESET}")
            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}----------------------------------------{Fore.RESET}")
            first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
            latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
            x = latest_email_id + 1
            n = 0
            for i in range(first_email_id,x):
                data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)' )
                for response_part in data:
                    arr = response_part[0]
                    if isinstance(arr, tuple):
                        msg = email.message_from_string(str(arr[1],'utf-8'))
                        for part in msg.walk():
                            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                                plain_text = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                                str_enc = str(plain_text)
                                extractor = URLExtract()
                                extractor.update()
                                urls = extractor.find_urls(str_enc)
                                str_url = str(urls).replace("\\","").replace("rnrn'","").replace('"','').replace("[","").replace("]","")
                                to = msg['to']
                                rancolor = random.choice(color)
                                print(f"[{Fore.MAGENTA}{n}{Fore.RESET}] {rancolor}[ {to} ] Found Verification Link {Fore.RESET}")
                                n += 1
                                save = open("list.txt", "a")
                                save.write(f"{str_url}\n")
                                save.close()
```

Comment: your function is empty. you need to put some code inside it, otherwise python will throw you an error

Comment: In your example session you input `2` for the number of threads. Why do you expect just one of each word from the `data` list?

Comment: Do you want to see one...nine only once? That is not how you use threads in order to make it print faster, if it ever going to be faster than just looping over and printing the data...

Comment: Each of the two threads will print one, two, three and so on. So `one` will be printed two times, same for `two` and so on. Both threads run at the same time and both print the order in which that happens is undefined. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: btw if you are expecting `one` and then `two` without a blank line in-between, then you should remove the `'\n'` from your `print()`

Comment: @M.Spiller is just sample code , i have loop to read email , without multithread , read email so slow , so i want to use multithread for get faster. in case "my example code" i got problem when use multithread the coding print double value.

Comment: All we can see is the code you provided. We know nothing about how you are actually reading email. All we can tell is that your printing will be interleaved in some fashion.

Comment: Well same for your _real_ code. Each thread will read all mails and process them. Both threads writing to the same file will get you a messed up file

Comment: @M.Spiller so that impossible to make faster ?

Comment: Just divide the work into two parts and let each thread work on one of these parts, instead having two threads doing exactly the same thing. In your case, find out the number of mails and pass the number of mails to read (`first_email_id` and `latest_email_id` in your case) to each thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have essentially this code

```
            t0 = time()
            for id_ in id_list:
                data = mail.fetch(id_, '(RFC822)' )
                ...
            elapsed = time() - t0
```

and you complain that `elapsed` is "big". Ok.

Having e.g. two threads process that list will just result
in double work, not what you want, as both threads visit
each ID.

What you're looking for is
[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

```
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
                d = {pool.submit(read_message, id_, 60): id_ for id_ in id_list}
                for future in as_completed(futures):
                    id_ = d[future]
                    data = future.result()
                    ...

def read_message(id_: str):
    data = mail.fetch(id_, '(RFC822)' )
    return data
```

This will go faster than single threading, *if*
contention for the single [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is low because
network operations are "slow".

---

Using [multiprocesing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
impresses me as simpler than threading
for your initial try.

```
            with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
                for data in pool.map(read_message, id_list):
                    print(data)
                    ...
```